# my code is not executing

Tags: android, android-fragments

my app has no error yet it is showing an error "unfortunately zine has stopped"

### main activity.java

```
package piestudio.zine;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

 private Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


       NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
               getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUP((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout),toolbar);











    }

}
```

`

### navigation drawer activity

```
package piestudio.zine;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;




/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "testpref";
    public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER="user_learned_drawer";
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;


    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {


        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       mUserLearnedDrawer=Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,"false"));
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){

            mFromSavedInstanceState=true;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);

    }


    public void setUP(DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {

        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


    }


    public static void saveToPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName,defaultValue);
    }

}
```

now as you can see the code , now whenever i try to run this on my phone (as my emulator is not working ) it stops by saying ##  **unfortunatley,zine has stopped**

Comment: please post your logcat too..

Comment: post your logcat of the crash

Comment: [link](http://hastebin.com/cihowefazo.avrasm)

logcat

Comment: @SripadRaj 


have a look [link](http://hastebin.com/acoburozex.avrasm)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this code

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
```

to this

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

and see whether the crash is happening or not. Please logcat output so that we can debug the crash in a better manner.

Comment: `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;` has this already so it should not make any difference

Comment: then why is he coded like android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar instead of Toolbar?
toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

Comment: the import is from the support library so there is nothing wrong

Comment: Is it because of any error present in my "extends name of activity"

Comment: the error is because of this Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: @swathin i will try tomorrow and i will get back to you once i try this :)_

Comment: this time i tried with AppCompatActivity  and yet the app force closing

Comment: @Swathin i tried changing it to Theme.AppCompat.Light . yet the error is there  [link](http://hastebin.com/acoburozex.avrasm)     check the log please